# Could anyone show me how to get from $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ne^{-xn}$ to $\frac{e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could anyone show me how to get from $\sum_{n=0}^\infty ne^{-xn}$ to $\frac{e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}$?

I was wondering if anyone could show me how to get from the sum on the left to the fraction on the right (if that fraction is even correct).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Justify term-by-term differentiation of $\sum e^{-nx}$

Answer (score 2):

If $\lvert x\rvert<1$, then$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n=\frac x{(1-x)^2}.$$Now, apply this with $e^{-x}$ instead of $x$.

Comment: For the OP: this can be obtained by differentiating the geometric series.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n\ge0}ne^{-xn}=\sum_{n\ge0}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{-xn}=\sum_{k\ge0}\sum_{n\ge k+1}e^{-xn}=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{e^{-x(k+1)}}{1-e^{-x}}=\frac{e^{-x}}{(1-e^{-x})^2}=\frac{e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}.$$